# Static Colormap in Scatter Plot during Addition of Datapoints

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, gif, colormap

I would like to add the datapoints to a locked portion of the screen one after the other, save all plots as a *.png and make a gif. Everything is working so far, but I want to lock the colorbar, so that it does not change its range during the addition of the points. I have no idea on how to do tackle this problem...

The input data is (the `t_string` will be modified to make it work):

```
x = [2.803480599999999, 5.5502475000000056, 6.984381300000002, 4.115224099999998, 5.746583699999995, 8.971469500000019, 12.028179500000032, 13.451193300000014, 12.457393999999972, 12.027555199999998, 16.077930800000015, 5.021229700000006, 11.206380399999999, 7.903262600000004, 11.98195070000001, 12.21701, 10.35045, 10.231890000000002]

y = [11.961321698938578, 5.218986480632915, 5.211628408660906, 4.847852635777481, 4.936266162218553, 5.233256380128127, 5.441388698929861, 5.461721129728066, 5.722170570613203, 5.2698434785261545, 5.645419662253215, 4.617062894639794, 4.973357261130752, 5.906843248930297, 5.256517482861392, 5.537361432952908, 5.339542403148332, 5.376979880224148]

t_string = ['2019-10-7', '2019-10-13', '2019-11-10', '2019-11-16', '2019-11-17', '2019-11-23', '2019-11-24', '2019-11-27', '2019-12-1', '2019-12-4', '2019-12-8', '2019-12-21', '2019-12-23', '2019-12-25', '2019-12-27', '2020-1-2', '2020-1-5', '2020-1-9']
```

[image]

Below you find the whole code I used. It will create a new directory in your working directory and write all files in there, you will also find the .gif in there. It might be necessary to install some packages. Many thanks in ad

```
# Import some stuff
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates as mdates

from datetime import datetime
import pathlib
from pathlib import Path
import moviepy.editor as mpy



# Define Input
x = [2.803480599999999, 5.5502475000000056, 6.984381300000002, 4.115224099999998, 5.746583699999995, 8.971469500000019,
     12.028179500000032, 13.451193300000014, 12.457393999999972, 12.027555199999998, 16.077930800000015,
     5.021229700000006, 11.206380399999999, 7.903262600000004, 11.98195070000001, 12.21701, 10.35045,
     10.231890000000002]

y = [11.961321698938578, 5.218986480632915, 5.211628408660906, 4.847852635777481, 4.936266162218553, 5.233256380128127,
     5.441388698929861, 5.461721129728066, 5.722170570613203, 5.2698434785261545, 5.645419662253215, 4.617062894639794,
     4.973357261130752, 5.906843248930297, 5.256517482861392, 5.537361432952908, 5.339542403148332, 5.376979880224148]

t_string = ['2019-10-7', '2019-10-13', '2019-11-10', '2019-11-16', '2019-11-17', '2019-11-23', '2019-11-24',
            '2019-11-27', '2019-12-1', '2019-12-4', '2019-12-8', '2019-12-21', '2019-12-23', '2019-12-25', '2019-12-27',
            '2020-1-2', '2020-1-5', '2020-1-9']

# Define a function to get the datafiles with a certain suffix in a path
def getfile_UI(file_directory, file_suffix):

    from glob import glob
    path_to_search = file_directory / file_suffix
    filenames = glob(str(path_to_search))

    return filenames


# Start of script/calculations
t = [mdates.date2num(datetime.strptime(i, "%Y-%m-%d")) for i in t_string]

workingdirectory_projectfolder = Path.cwd().parent

my_dpi = 75

for index, entry in enumerate(t_string):
    fig = plt.figure(figsize=(480 / my_dpi, 480 / my_dpi), dpi=my_dpi)
    sc = plt.scatter(x[0:index + 1],
                     y[0:index + 1],
                     c=t[0:index + 1])
    plt.xlim(0, 20)
    plt.ylim(4, 7)
    plt.title(entry)

    plt.xlabel("Distace [km]")
    plt.ylabel("Pace [min/km]")

    loc = mdates.AutoDateLocator()
    fig.colorbar(sc, ticks=loc,
                 format=mdates.AutoDateFormatter(loc))

    filename = 'png_' + str(index) + '.png'
    new_dir = workingdirectory_projectfolder /  "type 3 gif"
    pathlib.Path(new_dir).mkdir(exist_ok=True)

    plt.savefig(workingdirectory_projectfolder / "type 3 gif" / filename, dpi=96)
    plt.gca()

# Make a GIF from all png files
#       http://superfluoussextant.com/making-gifs-with-python.html
fps = 10
gif_name = str(fps) + " fps_""type3_"
workingdirectory_projectfolder = Path.cwd().parent
gif_path = workingdirectory_projectfolder / "type 3 gif" / gif_name

filenamelist_path = workingdirectory_projectfolder / "type 3 gif"
filenamelist_png = getfile_UI(filenamelist_path, "*.png")

list.sort(filenamelist_png, key=lambda x: int(
    x.split('_')[1].split('.png')[0]))  # Sort the images by #, this may need to be tweaked for your use case

clip = mpy.ImageSequenceClip(filenamelist_png, fps=fps)
clip.write_gif('{}.gif'.format(gif_path), fps=fps)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could call `plt.scatter` with `vmin=min(t), vmax=max(t)`. This fixes the limits used for coloring.

Something else you could add in your animation is to only show the tick dates up to the current:

```py
loc = mdates.AutoDateLocator()
cbar = fig.colorbar(sc, ticks=loc, format=mdates.AutoDateFormatter(loc))
ticks = [ti for ti in cbar.get_ticks() if ti <= t[index]]
cbar.set_ticks(ticks)
```

Comment: Thanks for the remarks, this drastically improves the quality of my GIF !